# ViewPager still lazy despite of preloading content

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-webview

I have a ViewPager with WebView content. Because it was not very smooth, I tried to create and load all WebViews before showing them. In my `onCreateView`of the fragement, I simply take the preloaded WebView from an array and add it to the layout. But it still is very lazy when I visit a page the first time. After that, it works smooth. I also tried to set my pager with `setOffscreenPageLimit()`, but it has no effect. What else can I do?

EDIT:
Here is my activity:

```
public class TutorialActivity extends FragmentActivity {
/**
 * The number of pages (wizard steps) to show in this demo.
 */
private static final int NUM_PAGES = 5;

/**
 * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous
 * and next wizard steps.
 */
private ViewPager mPager;

/**
 * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
 */
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutorial);

    // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(NUM_PAGES);
}


/**
 * A simple pager adapter that represents 5 {@link TutorialScreenSlidePageFragment} objects, in
 * sequence.
 */
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        TutorialScreenSlidePageFragment.init(TutorialActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return TutorialScreenSlidePageFragment.create(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
}
```

and my Pagefragement:

```
public class TutorialScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {
/**
 * The argument key for the page number this fragment represents.
 */
public static final String ARG_PAGE = "page";

private static final String assetPath = "file:///android_asset/tutorial/";

/**
 * The fragment's page number, which is set to the argument value for
 * {@link #ARG_PAGE}.
 */
private int mPageNumber;

static WebView[] webviews;

/**
 * Factory method for this fragment class. Constructs a new fragment for the
 * given page number.
 */
public static TutorialScreenSlidePageFragment create(int pageNumber) {
    TutorialScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new TutorialScreenSlidePageFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public TutorialScreenSlidePageFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout containing a title and body text.
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_tutorial_screen_slide_page, container, false);

    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webviewContainer);
    vg.addView(webviews[mPageNumber]);

    return rootView;
}

/**
 * Returns the page number represented by this fragment object.
 */
public int getPageNumber() {
    return mPageNumber;
}

// preload data
public static void init(Context context) {
    webviews = new WebView[5];

    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        WebView webview = new WebView(context);
        webview.loadUrl(String.format("%sonboard%d.html", assetPath, x + 1));
        // Only disabled the horizontal scrolling:
        webview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(
                LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        webviews[x] = webview;
    }
```

Most of it is just copied from google examples. In my PagerAdapter, i try to init all webviews and load their url.

When I say it is not smooth, I mean there is no smooth scrolling from page 1 to 2 to 3 at the first time. After stepping through all pages, it is working like a charm.

Comment: `setOffscreenPageLimit` by default is 1, if we try to set a value less than 1, it is assumed in the first place 
this value. But what is actually slow, the swiper? the data load? 
I think is interesting you show the code snippet that contains the Adapter and the Fragment / view of each page of the ViewPager..

Comment: "What else can I do?" -- you can figure out where your problem lies, through logging (Java and, if relevant, JavaScript in the Web content) and through tools (e.g., Traceview). You might also consider explaining, in greater detail, what you mean by "not very smooth".

Comment: Ok, I edited my original post with some more information.